# Will spamassassin’s bayes filter work if learned spam mails have *SPAM* in the subject?

Tags: spam, spamassassin

When my mail setup detects that a mail is spam, it puts `*SPAM*` in the subject. Now I want to improve my bayes filter by training it on my corpus of spam.

If I feed these thousands of mails to `sa-learn`, will that work even if they still have the `*SPAM*` in the subject? Or will it have the effect of telling the filter “something is only spam if it has `*SPAM*` in the header”, which would be counter-productive?

Comment: Yes, no and no again.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the man page](https://spamassassin.apache.org/full/3.1.x/doc/sa-learn.html) for `sa-learn`, this will be okay.

> If the messages you are learning from have already been filtered
>   through SpamAssassin, the learner will compensate for this. In effect,
>   it learns what each message would look like if you had run
>   spamassassin -d over it in advance.